# Return Related Books in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to return a book related to a book using the author's name

I have this function in my Controller

```
public function show(Book $book) {

        $book = Book::where('id', '=', $book)->first();
        $related = Book::whereHas('author_id', function ($q) use ($book) {
        return $q->whereIn('name', $post->author->pluck('id')); 
        })
        ->where('id', '!=', $book->id) // So I won't fetch same post
        ->get();
        return view('book')
        ->with($book)
        ->with($related); 
}
```

This is the way my `book table` looks like

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->text('about');
        $table->string('image');  
        $table->string('image_url');
        $table->string('epub_url');
        $table->integer('author_id'); 
        $table->string('publisher');  
        $table->year('year');
        $table->boolean('recommended')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();    
    });
}
```

I have done this in my models

```
public function books()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Book::class);
}
```

In `Book`model

```
public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Author::class);
    }
```

I have done this, and this is not working for me, as I don't know what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: from where the `show` method gets `Book` object? I think it should be like `show( $book)` only. If you have stackTrace, please post it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have your `$book`, you can easily load other books by the same author by querying the `author_id` field. Just make sure to exclude the original book from the query, and you're good to go.

```
$relatedBooks = Book::where('author_id', $book->author_id)
  ->where('id', '!=', $book->id)
  ->get();
```

As a side note, you're already passing an instance of Book in your method arguments, so the first line of your code (`$book = Book::where('id', '=', $book)->first();`) is redundant, you can simply use `$book`.

Answer (score 0):

You are querying the wrong way. what you can do is first get the book with author as given,

```
$book = Book::with(['author'])->where(['id' => $BOOK_ID])->first();
```

then you can load the similar books from the same authors as given

```php
$similarBooks = Book::whereHas('author' => function($query) use ($book){
    $query->where(['id' => $book->author->id]);
})->where('id' , '!=' , $book->id)->get();
```

Alternatively you can load by the author's name by replacing the relation's query.

Comment: This returned 
`Undefined variable: BOOK_ID`

Comment: Replace the BOOK_ID with the book id you have, like $book->id,